# Is there a way to partition a vector into odd and even numbers in place?

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to find all of the even numbers and move them all to the end of vector? The order doesn't matter, all that matters is that evens were moved to the end. However, it would be *nice* if order was preserved.

For example: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` => `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`

I'd like to have the signature `pub fn move_by_filter(nums: &mut Vec<i32>)`.

I tried to filter and combine vector slices, but I am running into a problem combining array slices:

```
let evens = nums.iter().filter(|&&i| i % 2 == 0).collect::<Vec<_>>();

let odds = nums.iter().filter(|&&i| i % 2 != 0).collect::<Vec<_>>();

// then I want to do something like: nums = odds.push(evens)
```

This doesn't `push` them to the end of the vector.

I'm not sure if it is the best approach since I have to use `iter()` twice (which is O(N) + O(N) I think, but would like to do it in one operation if possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to sort the vector with a custom sort key:

```
pub fn sort_by_parity(nums: &mut [i32]) {
    nums.sort_by_key(|&x| x % 2 == 0);
}
```

Rust's standard sort algorithm is stable, so this will preserve the original order of the odd and even numbers.

The closure passed to create sort keys evaluates to `false` for odd numbers and to `true` for even numbers. This makes sure that all odd numbers are sorted before the even numbers.

Instead of accepting a mutable reference to a vector, this function accepts a mutable slice reference, which is more generic.

The runtime of this approach is O(n log n), which is not optimal for in-place partitioning. You can achieve linear runtime, O(n), e.g. using the [`partition()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) method:

```
pub fn partition_by_parity(nums: &mut [i32]) {
    let (even, odd): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = nums.iter().partition(|&x| x % 2 == 0);
    nums[..odd.len()].copy_from_slice(&odd);
    nums[odd.len()..].copy_from_slice(&even);
}
```

The runtime difference between the two approaches is unlikely to matter in practice.

If you don't require to preserve the original order of the odd and even elements, you can partition the slice in place in linear time, without needing an additional buffer. Rust Nightly offers the unstable [`partition_in_place()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition_in_place) method for this purpose, but it's not too difficult to implement yourself – it's basically the partitioning step in Quicksort.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, this is great. I didn't know about sort_by_key. Thank you!

Comment: What sorting algorithm does `sort_by_key` use?

Comment: @HeapOverflow The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#current-implementation-8) describes it: *The current algorithm is an adaptive, iterative merge sort inspired by timsort.* You can also click the [src] button to read the source code; all of Rust's standard library is open source.

Comment: @HeapOverflow You may also want to read the [PR implementing the current version of the sort algorithm](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38192) if you are interested in this kind of thing. It's a good read. Rust also includes [an unstable sort algorithm](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/40601).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting it's O(m n log(m n)), I would've thought O(m n log(n)). Can't imagine how the extra m gets into the log. Partially I asked because I thought you said it's in place, I see now I misread that. But is O(n log n) really optimal for stable partitioning in place? [This](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~jyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf) seems to say it can be done in O(n) (but I didn't read it all).

Comment: @HeapOverflow You are right, I assumed stable sort doesn't allocate an additional buffer, but it does, in fact, allocate a buffer of half the size of the original slice. If you allow for additional storage, you can of course do it in linear time.

Comment: @HeapOverflow The m in the complexity appears to be a mistake.

Comment: Am I misinterpreting the paper? Their second paragraph defines the problem and it sounds exactly like what we have here, and their first paragraph says they can do it in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @HeapOverflow This is indeed what the abstract and the theorem says, but it doesn't seem what they proof. It looks like they need O(log(n)) additional space, not O(1).